# Загрузка в одной странице

Tags: php

Есть таблица peoples и столбцы id text code. В файле test.php имеются ссылки на code "3", "4", "5". Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии ссылки 3 файл перегружался и выводился список text, которые имеют code 3?

Я надеюсь кто-нибудь такое делал и у него есть конкретный пример, с которым поделитесь. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос чуть не понял, но попробую ответить. Если я ошибаюсь не ставьте минус.

```
   <?
    $с = $_POST['code'];
    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT id, text, code FROM `peoples` WHERE `code` = '.$c) or die (mysql_error()); 
    print"<table width='100%' border='1'>";  
    $i=1;
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    print "<tr><td width='10%'>".$i."</td><td width='90%' align='center'>".$r['text']."</td></tr>";
    $i++;
    }
    print"</table>";
    ?>
```

Ссылка  примеров `<a href='index.php?code=3'> Code 3 </a>`

Comment: С поправкой:

    if(isset($_GET['code'])){
        $с = (int) $_GET['code'];
        ...
    }

И скобку после второго принта закрыть.